# How to change foreign key reference from one column of a table to another column of another table in oracle sql developer

Tags: sql, oracle-sqldeveloper

I have 3 master tables for state,district and mandal.

- a_state_mst (state_id is the pk)
- b_district_mst (district_id is the pk)
- c_mandal_mst (mandal_id is the pk)

pk = primary key

I have given the above columns to some tables as foreign key reference.

I have other 3 master tables for state,district and mandal.

- d_state_mst (state_id is the pk)
- e_district_mst (district_id is the pk)
- f_mandal_mst (mandal_id is the pk)

I want to change the foreign key reference from a_state_mst table(state_id) to d_state_mst(state_id), b_district_mst(district_id) to e_district_mst(district_id) and similarly for mandal.

I tried changing directly from the constraints section but that didn't get updated.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to change the foreign key constraint from one table to another,

Then you need to [drop the existing one](https://docs.oracle.com/javadb/10.6.2.1/ref/rrefsqlj81859.html).

The syntax is :

```
alter table <child_table> DROP CONSTRAINT <foreign_key_constraint_name>;
```

and then add a new foreign key constraint on new table using [ADD CONSTRAINT](https://docs.oracle.com/javadb/10.6.2.1/ref/rrefsqlj81859.html) command.

```
alter table <child_table> ADD CONSTRAINT <foreign_key_constraint_name> FOREIGN KEY (<child_table_column>) REFERENCES <parent_table> (<parent_table_column>);
```